# Exception with Cmis method getAllVersions: CmisNotSupportedException: Operation not supported by the repository for this object

Tags: java, cmis, opencmis

i'm certainly desperate with this, i hope someone have some idea about what thing is missing in my server implementation of CMIS, or what is wrong in the server side.

I have implemented my Cmis server using Apache chemistry-opencmis, these are the dependencies in the pom:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
      <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-server-support</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.chemistry.opencmis</groupId>
      <artifactId>chemistry-opencmis-server-bindings</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion> <!-- Due to GWT compiler error -->
          <groupId>asm</groupId>
          <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

All seems working less when i try to call the **getAllVersions** method (that i have already implemented in the server side) from the client, getting this exception: **CmisNotSupportedException: Operation not supported by the repository for this object!**

I tested it with the following code, targeting to an existing document:

```
Session session = getSession();

Document doc = (Document) session.getObject("dddfd49f-ab13-435d-b65c-7e18d3bfbed3");


doc.getAllVersions();
```

Getting the mentioned exception. 
In relation with the **DocumentTypeDefinitionImpl** i have **setIsVersionable** to true:

CMIS Workbench: https://i.ibb.co/zSPCLRN/image.png

Debugging the client with the mentioned test, the problem is that never does reach the server method **getAllVersions** throwing the client the mentioned exception before, it tries to get this link **http://localhost:8081/cmis/atom/default/versions?id=dddfd49f-ab13-435d-b65c-7e18d3bfbed3** from its links cache (it is a map) with this key **version-history**, but this key is not in their cache of links, this is the class i'm referring

**org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.VersioningServiceImpl**

and this is just the code:

```
@Override
    public List<ObjectData> getAllVersions(String repositoryId, String objectId, String versionSeriesId, String filter,
            Boolean includeAllowableActions, ExtensionsData extension) {
        List<ObjectData> result = new ArrayList<ObjectData>();

        // find the link
        String link = loadLink(repositoryId, objectId, Constants.REL_VERSIONHISTORY, Constants.MEDIATYPE_FEED);

        if (link == null) {
            throwLinkException(repositoryId, objectId, Constants.REL_VERSIONHISTORY, Constants.MEDIATYPE_FEED);
        }
```

The method **loadLink** is returning null, so it launch the mentioned exception, because he does not find the mentioned link.

Even if i call the link **http://localhost:8081/cmis/atom/default/versions?id=dddfd49f-ab13-435d-b65c-7e18d3bfbed3** thru the browser Chrome, it reaches correctly to the **getAllVersions** method in the server side, and working fine.

The exception i get is this:

```
org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisNotSupportedException: Operation not supported by the repository for this object!
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.AbstractAtomPubService.throwLinkException(AbstractAtomPubService.java:294)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.bindings.spi.atompub.VersioningServiceImpl.getAllVersions(VersioningServiceImpl.java:276)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.DocumentImpl.getAllVersions(DocumentImpl.java:385)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.tck.impl.AbstractSessionTest.checkVersionHistory(AbstractSessionTest.java:1813)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.checks.ObjectComplianceCheck.run(ObjectComplianceCheck.java:55)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.tck.impl.AbstractSessionTest.run(AbstractSessionTest.java:181)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.tck.impl.AbstractCmisTestGroup.run(AbstractCmisTestGroup.java:115)
    at org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.workbench.details.ObjectPanel$3.actionPerformed(ObjectPanel.java:346)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
  Exception: Operation not supported by the repository for this object!
```

Comment: Are you giving the right object id ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server does not provide a link to the `versions` resource although the document is marked as versionable.

Set the version series ID in the `ObjectInfo` object. That should add the missing link.